# The characters of group elements in the regular representation

Tags: group-theory, group-representations, representation-theory

According to A. Zee's Group theory in a Nutshell for Physicists ([Chapter II.2](https://books.google.com/books/about/Group_Theory_in_a_Nutshell_for_Physicist.html?id=FWkujgEACAAJ)), for a finite group, the character of any element other than the identity vanishes in the regular representation.

However, let us consider $S_3$. One element is $(12)$ which is represented by the following matrix
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right),
$$
whose character, ie, the trace, is $1$! Is Zee wrong?

Comment: Indeed to complement @Javier's answer the group multiplication table for $S_3$ is $$\begin{array}{c|cccccc}
  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\ \hline
 1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
 2 & 2 & 1 & 4 & 3 & 6 & 5 \\
 3 & 3 & 5 & 1 & 6 & 2 & 4 \\
 4 & 4 & 6 & 2 & 5 & 1 & 3 \\
 5 & 5 & 3 & 6 & 1 & 4 & 2 \\
 6 & 6 & 4 & 5 & 2 & 3 & 1 \\
\end{array}$$ from which you can extract the $6\times 6$ matrices for the various elements and quickly verify that none other than the unit has any diagonal entries.

Comment: This appears to be a pure math question with no physics context. Might it be better suited for [math.SE]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want the action of $S_3$ on $\{1,2,3\}$; you want its action on itself, that's the definition of regular representation.

For starters, since $S_3$ has six elements, its associated vector space is six dimensional, so for starters your matrix must have dimension six, not three. To compute that matrix, you need to calculate the product of $(12)$ with all six group elements, not its action on $\{1,2,3\}$. If you do that, you should get the right result.